# Unable to open a newly created Maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, workspace

I created a new maven project using the following maven command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.company.lib_name -DartifactId=lib_name -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

When I open this newly created project in eclipse it gives the following error:

```
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-  plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its    dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.3.2: Hostname cannot be null
```

I tried th following:

1. Deleted the .m2/repository and rebuilt the project
2. Verified that the artifact exists in the maven repo
3. Maven user settings point to the correct settings.xml
4. Project compiles on the command line
5. Cleaned the project
6. Forced updates n the project
7. Checked repo to see all the dependencies are downloaded
8. Change eclipse to use the external maven instead of embeded
   Also I am using Kepler and Maven 3.

Any idea what 'hostname cannot be null' is pointing at?

THis is the pom content

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.company.lib</groupId>
  <artifactId>liby</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>lib</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.0</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>
 </project>
```

And the settings.xml

```
<settings>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Blah</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>inhouse</id>
                <url>http://mavenrepo/maven2_repositories/inhouse</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>inhouse_snapshot</id>
                <url>http://mavenrepo/maven2_repositories/inhouse_snapshot</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>inhouse</id>
                <url>http://mavenrepo/maven2_repositories/inhouse</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>inhouse_snapshot</id>
                <url>http://mavenrepo/maven2_repositories/inhouse_snapshot</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile> 
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>company_name</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>central-to-nexus</id> 
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://mw_maven_repository_readonly/nexus/content/groups/cached</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: I assume  you have a space right before the -DarchetypeArtifactId ??

Comment: Did you tell eclipse about your repo?  run: mvn -Declipse.workspace=<path-to-eclipse-workspace> eclipse:add-maven-repo

Comment: Have you tried -DinteractiveMode=true   or just leaving that switch out? there may be additional input it needed

Comment: HI Micho - Yes there is a space. Thank you for flagging.Also tried the command to add repo for eclipse. No luck

Comment: Hi Vinny: Tried with the true switch. No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers. but the problem was with the maven repo url.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have created the project from Maven Template but you did not make this project as an Eclipse project before import it in Eclipse.

So after create a new maven project using the maven command you should also execute the below command to make the project as an Eclipse project

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

It will generate all project files that are required by Eclipse IDE.

I also prefer to execute **"mvn clean install"** before import the project in Eclipse.

Comment: @ruby Try this : Execute “mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse clean install” command from command line & then refresh the project from eclipse.

Comment: add content of pom.xml & settings.xml in ur question.

Comment: plz also add the settings.xml content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77117/discussion-between-ruby-and-arin).

Answer (score 0):

**At command prompt :**

mvn eclipse:eclipse 
mvn clean install

This should download all dependencies